# I want to replace a char (/) with another char (¿) inside a specific text range of a column (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

The problem is that the column has a lot of text and I just want to make this change within a specific text range.

Per example, the column is populated with this data:

...

```
<PropertyBagV2>
            <Item Name="Inventory_Document">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value />
                </ValueList>
            </Item>
            <Item Name="SupplierPartnerNo">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value />
                </ValueList>
            </Item>
            <Item Name="LabelNumber">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value>253938478/L44704428</Value>
                </ValueList>
            </Item>
            <Item Name="PalletProductList">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value>L44704428/253938478/C01/NOUPLOAD/NOUPLOAD/1/MTPR/MTPR</Value>
                    <Value>L44704428/253938478/90099326/311/NOUPLOAD/10/MTPR/MTPR</Value>
                </ValueList>
            </Item>
        </PropertyBagV2>
    </SessionContext>
```

...

But I want to substitue the '/' with '¿' only from segment 'L%' to '/MTPR<'. Basically, on these 2 parts:

```
<Value>L44704428/253938478/C01/NOUPLOAD/NOUPLOAD/1/MTPR/MTPR</Value>                 
<Value>L44704428/253938478/90099326/311/NOUPLOAD/10/MTPR/MTPR</Value>
```

Is there a way to do this in ORACLE?
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Eduardo

Comment: http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-string-functions/oracle-regexp_replace/

Comment: you can use `updatexml` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm

Comment: The problem on updatexml is to define the text range, because all columns have '<Value>L' and '/MTPR' in common, however, the data between is always different.

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE maybe would work, will try to define well the start position

Comment: Just used:

update table
set message=REGEXP_REPLACE(message, '/', '¿', 1560, 7)
where id=155398943;

But only 1 char was changed, not 7. What is the problem?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very convoluted SQL statement that does what you desire. I couldn't figure out how to constrain the regexp_replace to the row with the value list, so I split the text into multiple rows, did the replace, and then recombined it.

```
WITH
-- Original value to be replaced
aset AS( SELECT q'[<PropertyBagV2>
        <Item Name="Inventory_Document">
            <ValueList>
                <Value />
            </ValueList>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="SupplierPartnerNo">
            <ValueList>
                <Value />
            </ValueList>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="LabelNumber">
            <ValueList>
                <Value>253938478/L44704428</Value>
            </ValueList>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="PalletProductList">
            <ValueList>
                <Value>L44704428/253938478/C01/NOUPLOAD/NOUPLOAD/1/MTPR/MTPR</Value>
                <Value>L44704428/253938478/90099326/311/NOUPLOAD/10/MTPR/MTPR</Value>
            </ValueList>
        </Item>
    </PropertyBagV2>
</SessionContext>]' AS t, CHR( 10 ) AS lf FROM DUAL ),
-- Split the record into multiple records using the trailing line feed as the separator
    splitit ( t
            , REMAINDER
            , lf
            , r ) AS
        (                         -- Ensure the last line is included by adding a trailing line feed
         SELECT SUBSTR( t || lf, 1, INSTR( t || lf, lf ) - 1 )     AS t
              , SUBSTR( t || lf, INSTR( t, lf ) + 1 )              AS REMAINDER
              , lf
              , 1                                                  AS r
           FROM aset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT SUBSTR( REMAINDER, 1, INSTR( REMAINDER, lf ) - 1 )     AS t
              , SUBSTR( REMAINDER, INSTR( REMAINDER, lf ) + 1 )        AS REMAINDER
              , lf
              , r + 1                                                  AS r
           FROM splitit
          WHERE REMAINDER IS NOT NULL AND t IS NOT NULL),
    repl AS
        (SELECT t
              ,                
              -- Only replace slashes on records starting with spaces and <value>L
              -- 'i' makes the match case insensitive
                CASE
                    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( t, '^ *<value>L.*</value>$', 'i' )
                    THEN
                        -- I am using ' boo ' instead of odd character questioner
                        -- requested. Substitute your own string for ' boo '
                        REPLACE( t, '/', ' boo ' )
                    ELSE
                        -- no match, just return original string
                        t
                END    replaced
              , r
           FROM splitit)
-- LISTAGG will recombine the multiple records back into a single record
SELECT LISTAGG( replaced, CHR( 10 ) ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r)     AS t
  FROM repl
```